# In depth description of statically resolved type parameters

Tags: generics, types, f#

I'm looking for a very comprehensive review of statically resolved type parameters. What exactly can be done with them, what their limitations are, what are the effects of using them, how they combine with normal type parameters, and how do instance-level inline members work.

The specification itself offers very little on the subject, mentioning them only in passing. It says nothing about the ability to have types with such type parameters (e.g. `type Example< ^a>`), how exactly the keywords `and` and `or` can be used when specifying complex member constraints, how much member signatures have to conform to the signature of the constraint, and so forth.

I've really only found introductory material and some very specific information, nothing in the form of a comprehensive overview.

Comment: Have you read the MSDN docs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd548046.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233203.aspx ?

Comment: Of course, I'm looking for an in-depth overview. I've read the specification itself. There is barely any information at all.

Comment: How about [the F# source code](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp), then? That's quite in-depth, I should say.

Comment: @GregRos: Part of the reason would be that using those constructs is a bad idea in general and usually suggests that you're trying to brute force your way through the problem.

Comment: @MarkSeemann there's always that, yeah. I'm hoping there's an alternative. It could be difficult anyway, since the way different parts of the code interact wouldn't be obvious.

Comment: @scrwtp, why is using those constructs "a bad idea in general", and why does it imply I'm trying to "brute force" my way through a problem?

Comment: @GregRos: Statically resolved type parameters and static member constraints seem to be getting a disproportionate amount of attention here and around the web compared to how little they're used in my experience - and often this attention is focused on using them as a crutch to get around the type system in a pseudo-duck-typing, pseudo-type-class way, instead of fixing the design. My point is that an outsider might leave with a view that `^a`'s and static member constraints are somehow an indispensable tool for an F# programmer, which simply isn't true.

Comment: @GregRos: But if what you're doing is strictly generic numeric code (for which statically resolved type parameters where designed), just ignore my comment.

Comment: @scrwtp I disagree, generic numeric code becomes complicated quickly when you need to use generic numbers and restricted operators. Static type constraints solve just a part of the problem here. On the other hand, do you think [Fleece](https://github.com/mausch/Fleece) is a bad design that could have be done better using another technique?

Comment: @Gustavo: Fleece actually looks nice - that's probably the first time I'm seeing code where such an approach doesn't feel forced. But then again, when constraints are used there, they're used sparingly.